# What is the difference between a model object queried by filter and an object queried by get() in Django?

Tags: database, django, orm

I keep coming across this issue where I am trying to update a record using the update() method.

It always works when I query an object using filter.

```
my_dictionary = {"key":"Val","another":"Val"}
thing = Thing.objects.filter(pk=1)
```

<strike>thing[0].update(**my_dictionary)</strike> wrote it wrong in the original question.

```
thing.update(**my_dictionary)
```

When I query the object using get() it keeps telling me that the object has no method update()

```
my_dictionary = {"key":"Val","another":"Val"}
thing = Thing.objects.get(pk=1) 
thing.update(**my_dictionary)
```

Isn't a model object the same in both cases? Why would one have an update method and the other one not? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: filter() return list of object or get return an object this why you can 't use update()with get()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters) is *very* explicit about this:

> filter() will always give you a QuerySet, even if only a single object matches the query - in this case, it will be a QuerySet containing a single element.
>
> If you know there is only one object that matches your query, you can use the get() method on a Manager which returns the object directly.

Your first snippet returns a QuerySet, which has an update method. The second snippet returns a model instance, which doesn't.

Note that you have not shown the exact code you are using: `thing[0].update` would give *exactly* the same error as the second snippet.

Comment: Yeah, you were right, I wrote the question wrong originally. So, in the case that the QuerySet returns a list of many objects, is the purpose of the update method to apply an update to all of the object in bulk?

Comment: Yes, update will modify all matching rows directly in the database, without actually fetching the instances.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `QuerySet.update()` and `ModelInstance.save().`

If you’re just updating a record and don’t need to do anything with the model object, the most efficient approach is to call update(), rather than loading the model object into memory. For example, instead of doing this:

> e = Entry.objects.get(id=10)
>
> e.comments_on = False
>
> e.save()

...do this:

> Entry.objects.filter(id=10).update(comments_on=False)